# Django <-> SQL Server 2005, text encoding problem

Tags: sql-server, django, unicode, odbc, freetds

I'm trying to store Django data on MS SQL Server 2005 using:

http://code.google.com/p/django-pyodbc/
(pyodbc + FreeTDS)

As long as I'm storing string consist of ASCII characters everything is ok.
When I'm using unicode (ex. '\xc5\x82'), django throws ProgrammingError on:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/cli/punktrejestracji/add/
('42000', '[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) protocol stream is incorrect. The stream ended unexpectedly. (4002) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

last element of trace is:

```
params  ('\xc5\x82',)
self    <django.db.backends.sql_server.pyodbc.base.CursorWrapper object at 0x92ef8ec>
sql 'SELECT (1) AS [a] FROM [cli_punktrejestracji] WHERE [cli_punktrejestracji].[adres] = ? '
```

BTW http://code.google.com/p/django-mssql/ doesn't seems to work under Linux,
django-mssql needs pythoncom library. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the solution was found. In file freetds.conf there is

```
client charset = UTF-8
```

and it works exactly like it should.

Comment: We tried using that and while it fixed some of the error messages, it did not fix all of them. I hope it does it for you.

Comment: So do I :-) If not, we might need to change technology from django, to some other.

Comment: I woldn't mind hearing from you - maybe another comment here - if things work out OK with this. Alongside with the releases of Django and django-pyodbc you had success with... :-)

Comment: It's not exactly my project, another guy in the company is working on that - our department stick to open source solutions ;-) But I'll ask him in some time, how it goes and whether he has any successes with that.

Comment: It seems, that this solution is working. At least until this moment we haven't encountered any problems.

Answer (score 2):

We use Django with SQL Server 2005. We found the same problem you did.

What ODBC driver are you using? FreeTDS?

We tried finding a good ODBC driver for linux/unix to use that would not throw the error above (and others) when unicode would come into play - and failed miserably. None of the drivers we tested - at least three, I can dig the names up if you would like - had any success in dealing with unicode strings via django-pyodbc.

What we ended up doing, sad as it might sound, was to decide to run Django on a Windows server (Apache + mod_wsgi) and use the Microsoft's SQL Native ODBC driver.

It works just fine - unicode wise - when we do that.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the accepted response, it is possible to fix this error dirrectly in the settings.py :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'MyTableName',
        'HOST': r'server.lan\server_instance_name',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'P@SsW0Rd',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'host_is_server': True,
            "extra_params":"TDS_Version=8.0;ClientCharset=UTF-8",
            "autocommit": True,
            "driver_needs_utf8":True,
        },

     }
}
```

take a look at the `extra_params`

this don't rely on the global freetds.conf file, so it is better