# Django - How to save data into 'cp1251' database

Tags: python, django

I need to save data into external 1251 MSSQL database.

```
ee = Claim.objects.using('mssql').get(pk=1)
test = u'test'
ee.comment = test
ee.save(using='mssql')
```

But I get an error:`DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 0: invalid start byte. You passed in bytearray(b'\xbbu\xc09P\xf2\x00F\x8a\xd5T\x9a\xf9K\xff!') (<type 'bytearray'>)`

I tried to save data in this way:

```
tt = u'test'.decode('cp1251')
ee.comment = tt
```

But i've got same error. I will be thankful if you help me with it.

P.S.
this is my settings.py file :

```
'mssql': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'textures',
        'PASSWORD': 'testpassword',
        'HOST': 'MSSQL-PYTHON',
        'PORT': '1234',
        'OPTIONS': {
                'host_is_server': False,
                'dsn': 'MSSQL-PYTHON',
                'charset': 'cp1251',
                'use_unicode': True,
        },
    }
```

Comment: You don't want to *decode* an unicode string, you want to `encode()` an unicode string.

Comment: I have same error when `encode()`

Comment: I'm actually wondering why you have to do this at all. Did you setup the database charset correctly?

Comment: I just edit my post

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192982/django-sql-server-2005-text-encoding-problem) might help. `use_unicode` looks like a mysql settings to me and probably will do nothing for SQL server.